Prove two versions of Godel’s completeness are equivalent
In this notes:
https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/278xnotes/Lecture6-Completeness.pdf
Lurie says Theorem 5 implies Theorem 9 by adding constants and an axiom demands that the newly added constants satisfy $\psi$. I cannot follow this argument, may I please ask for an unfold of this argument?
At first I guess it was a typo and the $\psi$ should be $\psi \to \varphi$ instead. But after comparing with his categorical argument for Theorem 10 from Theorem 7, I do not think it is a typo.

There's no need to add constants here. Assume that for all $M\models T$, $M[\psi(\vec{x})]\subseteq M[\varphi(\vec{x})]$. This means that for all $M
\models T$, $M\models (\forall \vec{x})[\psi(\vec{x})\Rightarrow \varphi(\vec{x})]$. By Theorem 5, $T\vdash (\forall \vec{x})[\psi(\vec{x})\Rightarrow \varphi(\vec{x})]$. That's all there is to it.

To filter models $M$ of the first-order theory $T$ which satisfy $\psi$, it seems that one must add axiom satisify $\psi$ not a $\psi \to \varphi$. So it is not a typo.

@AlexKruckman Thank you! I did think like this but I would like to understand why he added constant in order to figure out what is he saying in the categorical argument for Theorem 10. Is it unnecessary there as well? I would appreciate any quick comment, but if it would be long, I would like to post a separate question.

Add constants $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n$ to $T$ (where $n$ is the number of free variables in $\varphi, \psi$), as well as the axiom $\psi(\vec{c})$. Now for every model $M$ of $T$ and every interpretation of the constants $\vec{c}$ satisfying the axiom, we have $M[\psi(\vec{c})] = M$, hence also $M[\varphi(\vec{c})] = M$, hence $\varphi(\vec{c})$ is true in the model. By applying theorem 5, we get that $\varphi(\vec{c})$ is provable in our extended theory, and we can translate this back to a proof of $\forall \vec{x}. \psi(\vec{x}) \to \varphi(\vec{x})$ in $T$ by replacing the constants with variables and the axiom with an assumption.
(But as Alex Kruckman suggests, this is somewhat unnecessary.)
